# Spring Batch saturating memory

Tags: spring, memory-leaks, out-of-memory, batch-processing, spring-batch

UPDATE:

I try to add some details because it's very important for me to solve this problem.

I made a batch which generates pdf documents from data which is present in some tables and saves pdf in a table. The batch is ok but the data to process is huge, so i decided to divide input data in 8 groups and process indipendently the 8 groups with 8 parallel steps.
Each step has it's own reader (named "readerX" for the step "X") and has the same processor and writer which is used by the other steps.

Elaboration goes well, but my client says that this batch uses too much memory (he looks at the "Working Set" parameter in perfmon). In particular the batch begins with 300Mb of used memory, then the used memory reaches 7GB, then decreases to 2GB and the batch finish with 1/2GB of allocated memory.

I paste the code of the job here, hoping someone could help me to find the problem (i guess i made some mistake in adapting the job to parallel processing).

I'm new to spring batch so i apologize for the "bad look".

```
<job id="myJob"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
    <step id="step1" next="step2">
        <tasklet ref="task1" />
    </step>
    <step id="step2" next="step3">
        <tasklet ref="task2" />
    </step>
    <step id="step3" next="decider">
        <tasklet ref="task3" />
    </step>
    <decision id="decider" decider="StepExecutionDecider">
        <next on="CASE X"   to="split1" />
        <end on="*"/>   
    </decision>
    <split id="split1" task-executor="taskExecutor" next="endStep">
        <flow>
            <step id="EXEC1">
                <tasklet><chunk reader="reader1" processor="processor" writer="writer" commit-interval="100"/>
                <listeners>
                    <listener ref="Listner" />
                </listeners>
                </tasklet>
            </step>
        </flow>
        <flow>
            <step id="EXEC2">
                <tasklet><chunk reader="reader2" processor="processor" writer="writer" commit-interval="100"/>
                <listeners>
                    <listener ref="Listner" />
                </listeners>
                </tasklet>
            </step>
        </flow>
        <flow>
            <step id="EXEC3">
                <tasklet><chunk reader="reader3" processor="processor" writer="writer" commit-interval="100"/>
                <listeners>
                    <listener ref="Listner" />
                </listeners>

                </tasklet>
            </step>
        </flow>
         <flow>
            <step id="EXEC4">
                <tasklet><chunk reader="reader4" processor="processor" writer="writer" commit-interval="100"/>
                <listeners>
                    <listener ref="Listner" />
                </listeners>

                </tasklet>
            </step>
        </flow>
         <flow>
            <step id="EXEC5">
                <tasklet><chunk reader="reader5" processor="processor" writer="writer" commit-interval="100"/>
                <listeners>
                    <listener ref="Listner" />
                </listeners>
                </tasklet>
            </step>
        </flow>
         <flow>
            <step id="EXEC6">
                <tasklet><chunk reader="reader6" processor="processor" writer="writer" commit-interval="100"/>
                <listeners>
                    <listener ref="Listner" />
                </listeners>

                </tasklet>
            </step>
        </flow>
         <flow>
            <step id="EXEC7">
                <tasklet><chunk reader="reader7" processor="processor" writer="writer" commit-interval="100"/>
                <listeners>
                    <listener ref="Listner" />
                </listeners>
                </tasklet>
            </step>
        </flow>
         <flow>
            <step id="EXEC8">
                <tasklet><chunk reader="reader8" processor="processor" writer="writer" commit-interval="100"/>              
                <listeners>
                    <listener ref="Listner" />
                </listeners>
                </tasklet>
            </step>
        </flow>
    </split>
    <step id="endStep" next="decider">
        <tasklet ref="task4" >
            <listeners>
                <listener ref="Listner" />
            </listeners>
        </tasklet>
    </step>
</job>

<bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor"/>

<bean id="reader1" class="class of the reader">
    <property name="idReader" value="1"/>   // Different for the 8 readers 
    <property name="subSet" value="10"/>    // Different for the 8 readers 
    <property name="dao" ref="Dao" />
    <property name="bean" ref="Bean" /> 
    [...] // Other beans
</bean>
```

Thanks

Comment: do you get an out-of-memory as tagged, or not?

Comment: in my pc yes, on client server no.. but 7GB are too much for my client

Comment: Can you provide any insight into the error?  Exception?  Thread dump?  That configuration is used in countless production environments without issue so we're going to need a bit more to go on here.

Comment: I have no exception on the server, the batch executes successfully. The problem is that the client is monitoring my batch with perfmon and says that the Working Set reaches 7GB of memory... and it's too much.

Comment: There is too little information here. We need some code, thread dumps, etc else it won't be possible to assist you.

Comment: What is your reader data size and what is one pdf size? if you multiply it with 100 is equal to 1 step's memory consumption at its execution and multiply by 8 will be total memory consumption at any particular time of job execution. Hence could you please let us know what are above memory usage? In general more memory means fast execution time with high cpu usage. Lower the memory, lower cpu usage and more execution time. At the end of the day what we need to look is that whether there is any memory leak. which I believe is not there is this case.

Comment: Pdf max size is 400k, so 400k x 100 x 8 = 320 Mb in the worst case... not 8Gb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your getting an OOM eventually, first start by looking at the heap.

Start the JVM with -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError to obtain the HPROF which you can then look at to see object allocation, sizes etc. When the JVM exits with an OOM, this file will be generated (may take some time depending on size).

If your able to run with a larger memory foot print such as your clients machine, take a snapshot of the heap when its consuming a large amount such as the 7GB you mentioned (or any other value considered high - 4, 5, 6 etc). You should be able to invoke this while running via tools such as jconsole that come part of the JDK.

With the HPROF file, you can then inspect that with JDK provided tools such as jhat or a more GUI based tool such as the eclipse memory analyzer. This should give you a good (and relatively easy) way of finding out whats holding on to what and provide a starting point for decreasing footprint.

Answer (score 0):

Using a profiler and optimizing code i successfully limited memory consumption. Thanks to all!!!

Comment: What was the reason of this abnormal memory consumption ?

Comment: There was a bad configuration of the connection to the database... i don't know why after the problem was solved...

Answer (score 0):

> The batch is ok but the data to process is huge, so i decided to divide input data in 8 groups and process independently the 8 groups with 8 parallel steps.

If you are processing in parallel on the same machine it won't reduce the memory foot print. All the data exists in memory at the same time. If you want to decrease memory use you have to execute the steps  one after the other.